# Discover all delegates pointing to a controller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

Say you have a class

```
class Example:UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
    {
```

at any point in the life of the program, there may be (say) four little scroll views which have embedded themselves in an instance of Example, so those scroll views have said

```
aScrollView.delegate = someExample
bScrollView.delegate = someExample
```

and so on.

Is that information, indeed stored somehow, with someExample?

Obviously that information is stored with aScrollView - but is it also stored with someExample? Is the delegate connection two-way or strictly one-way? Can someExample examine itself and determine all the scrollviews which have been delegate'd to someExample?

So, is there a way for someExample to list all the scroll views currently connected to it in that way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate property is just a (usually weak) reference in the object that holds it.  For an object to keep back pointers to its "delegations", it would need to implement its own structure and do the bookkeeping for adding and removing itself.